# SQL Server 2014 - select statements with two contitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Here's the deal: I have a table that has a column for path and another column for date. Since I'm new into this SQL world I'm not sure what statement is more appropriate for this problem. It has to give me:

1. If date is null, the value of the path column or;
2. If date is not null, the value of the path column that has the latest date value in its date column.

It is important to note that in the end the table must not have any duplicates paths.

An example of how the table is looking right now:

```
path1         |----------------------------| 
path2         |----------------------------| 
path3         |2020-06-04 00:00:00| 
path3         |2020-06-03 00:00:00| 
path3         |----------------------------|
```

Now I have somewhat of a query that partially solves the problem, here it is:

```
select path_column, date_column 
from my_table a  
where a.date_column = (select max(date_column)  
                       from my_table b  
                       where a.path_column = b.path_column) 
   or date_column IS NULL
```

Result of the query above:

```
path1      |----------------------------| 
path2      |----------------------------| 
path3      |2020-06-04 00:00:00| 
path3      |----------------------------|
```

while I need it to look like this:

```
path1      |----------------------------| 
path2      |----------------------------| 
path3      |2020-06-04 00:00:00|
```

My organization is currently using SQL Server 2014. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by path1 order by date desc) as seqnum
      from my_table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

`NULL`s are considered to be the lowest value, so a descending sort puts them last.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `Group By` clause:-**

```
select path_column, max(date_column) date_column 
from my_table group by path_column;
```

**For demo data visit  [This Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=dd041218fc22effcfd30b04a8cf07361)**